# For lightning component how do we set numeric keyboard instead of qwerty keyboard for ui:inputNumber in touch devices?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

I've created a form inside a component with ui:inputNumber

```
<ui:inputNumer />
```

But on clicking it in my mobile device, i'm always getting a qwerty keyboard.

How do we set numeric keyboard instead?

Comment: `type="number" or type="Integer"` try if it work.

Comment: type is not a supported attribute @TusharSharma. 
The element name <ui:inputNumber> itself specifies it's a number

Comment: @TusharSharma i used normal <input type="number" /> instead of <ui:inputNumer /> it's working now.. :)

Comment: glad it is working.

Comment: @TusharSharma please have a look at this question too.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111777/is-there-a-way-to-replicate-the-default-task-detail-page-in-salesforce1-via-ligh

Answer (score 1):

The new lightning base component - lightning:input gives a number. its in beta but we are using this in prod apps it seems to work fine.

```
<lightning:input type="number" step="1" value="{!v.numberValue}" />
```

Answer (score -2):

1trailhead is good option.
2. you can go to marketing cloud app on salesforce and there will be help option
3. go to google search help salesforce marketing cloud
[click here for learning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220226&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&type=2)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73372)

Comment: i made it clear and gave only one link of salesforce that will never be broken.